# Reset the rank in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, dense-rank

I want to partition the data as given below. But as given in the [link](http://thehobt.blogspot.in/2009/02/rownumber-rank-and-denserank.html) there is no in built function which reset the Rank again staring from 1. I have tried `ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), DENSE_RANK()`.  So, can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

```
  Col1     Col2    Rank
cookie1    ABC      1
cookie1    ABC      1
cookie1    EFG      2
cookie1    EFG      2
cookie1    IJK      3
cookie1    IJK      3

cookie2    XYZ      1
cookie2    XYZ      1
cookie2    LMN      2
```

Comment: It seems like Rank is equal to session number according to your example. Then use substr(col2,8) to extract session number

Comment: You want to partition data according to which column or combination of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DENSE_RANK()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)  with PARTITION BY clause .

with temp as(

```
  select Col1      ,Col2  , DENSE_RANK() OVER   

  (PARTITION BY Col1      ORDER BY Col2  ) AS Rank 

  from rnktest 
 )
select *  from temp ;
```

[image]

Comment: hi what is the output

Comment: `FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException: One or more arguments are expected.
`

Answer (score 1):

There you go, you need `dense_rank` partition by first column and order by second one.

```
select *,dense_rank() over (partition by Col1 order by Col2) as rn from test_rank;
```

output:-

```
cookie1 ABC     1
cookie1 ABC     1
cookie1 EFG     2
cookie1 EFG     2
cookie1 IJK     3
cookie1 IJK     3

cookie2 LMN     1
cookie2 XYZ     2
cookie2 XYZ     2
```

Comment: No, It doesn't give the expected output. It gives the rank 1, 2, 3 etc even for the same session . Which i don't want. I want the same session value to be constant and once session value get changed it should be incremented by one.

Comment: So this case, you already has this required output in your question itself. if it is not then what else it is? could you then add more details to your question.

Comment: I have edited the values of sessionids. I think now you would be able to get what i am saying. you query gives the output like this where as i want as mentioned in the question. `cookie1    ABC      1
                                     cookie1    ABC      2`